# Android MediaController Play/Pause button and Seekbar doesn't Refresh

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-music-player

I am using MediaController.MediaPlayerControl in order to display a MediaController at the bottom of my Custom View but I can't get it to work properly. When I play music for first time then there should be pause button visible but instead there is play and when I press that button then the music is paused correctly and state remains the same and after that its working properly. Also when I play next song, the old MediaController widget gets overlapped with the new one. And sometimes the progress/seek bar doesn't refresh while the music is playing. It just updates itself when something on the MediaController is pressed (Play/Pause, forward, etc).

I found these questions similar to mine but I don't think the answers they got will solve my problem.

1. [Android mediacontroller Play Pause controls not refresh properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682680/android-mediacontroller-play-pause-controls-not-refresh-properly)
2. [Android MediaController seekbar not refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011631/android-mediacontroller-seekbar-not-refreshing)
3. [Android VideoView Playback Controls Show "Play" Initially Instead of "Pause" Even Though File is Already Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582818/android-videoview-playback-controls-show-play-initially-instead-of-pause-eve)

This is how I initialize the controller:

```
private void setController()
{
    controller = new MusicController(this);

    controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
          }
        }, new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            playPrev();
          }
        });

    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_list));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
}
```

This is how I show controller:

```
public void playMusic()
{
        musicSrv.playSong(); //Play song in a service
        setController();
        controller.show(0);
        controller.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Try calling invalidate?

Answer (score 12):

I had exactly this problem. Don't know if you still need help, but I thought I'd post anyway. For posterity, are you following [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-project-setup--mobile-22764)?

First, the easy problem: you're getting multiple instances of your controls because of repeated calls to `setController()`. Change the first line of your function to:

```
if (controller == null) controller = new MusicController(this);
```

With regards to the play button malfunctioning, I *believe* it's because you're showing it before the music player has been prepared (disclaimer: I'm a newbie to Android myself, and the following are the things I've found to have worked).

1. Set up a broadcast from your music-playing service to notify your music-controlling activity when the musicplayer has been prepared. Append the following function in your music-playing service to broadcast intent:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MusicPlayer player) {
       // Do some other stuff...

       // Broadcast intent to activity to let it know the media player has been prepared
       Intent onPreparedIntent = new Intent("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED");
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(onPreparedIntent);
   }
   ```
2. Set up a broadcast receiver in your music-controlling activity to receive the intent broadcast by your service. Add the following class to your activity:

   ```
   // Broadcast receiver to determine when music player has been prepared
   private BroadcastReceiver onPrepareReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
       // When music player has been prepared, show controller
       controller.show(0);
       }
   };
   ```
3. Register your receiver in your activity's `onResume()` method:

   ```
   // Set up receiver for media player onPrepared broadcast
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onPrepareReceiver,
           new IntentFilter("MEDIA_PLAYER_PREPARED"));
   ```
4. Depending on the structure of your code, you'll have to do some general tidying up. In my code, I've only called `setController()` twice: from the `onCreate()` and `onResume()` methods in my activity. I also only call `controller.show(0)` from my broadcast receiver, and my `onResume()` method.